# Images do not display in wordpress visual editor

Tags: image, wordpress, visual-editor

When i view the page created in visual editor i can not see it , instead i get an icon that sugests it's not loaded . 
I uploaded a image of this , hope it will explain better what i mean https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeoOy.jpg

Comment: what happens if you right click on those (non-loaded) images and paste the link into your browser. Does the image then load? If not, what is the link saying, does it match the correct path for your uploads folder directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is i don't add image files by wordpress , but directly write the path into static html pages .